# Why are not all my sites shown on the Stack Exchange reputation graph?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Stack Exchange reputation graph missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106333/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-missing)

As you can see on my [Stack Exchange reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/c02c96bc-1580-486f-9442-9321cf92ddde?tab=reputation), only the reputation from Stack Overflow is shown, yet I have [several linked accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/c02c96bc-1580-486f-9442-9321cf92ddde?tab=accounts) in the Stack Exchange network.

For other users, I see all their sites are mentioned, even if you have one site with a lot of reputation, and others with only a few points.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only those accounts with over 200 reputation are shown in the graph.  Area 51 reputation is not shown at all.

The 200 rep requirement also holds true for a site to be shown on your "combined flair" feature (see `http://[any SE site you have linked accounts on]/users/<youruseridnumber>/<yourusername>?tab=flair` or the `Flair` tab of your profile)