# Stack Exchange reputation graph missing

Tags: support, stack-exchange, reputation-graph

Is there a minimum reputation necessary before you can see the graph? If so how long does it take to update the graph? Because I've never been able to see mine on my Stack Exchange user account. All I see is a white box.

Comment: @Jeff I believe the bug tag says a "problem on the site that _you believe_ is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.    In any event, shouldn't there be a little note by the graph informing those with under 200 rep that they will be able to see it once they reach that point?

Comment: good idea; I'll ask the NY devs to add that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only sites on which you have at least 200 reputation will be shown, and the graph is only updated once per day (sometime after UTC midnight). It looks like you just passed the 200 reputation barrier on [Jewish Life and Learning](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/883/) (and Stack Overflow, thanks to the association bonus), so your graph should appear sometime in the next few hours.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the same apply to the Stack Exchange network flair?

Comment: It does, yes. I believe the flair is slightly different when it comes to updating (it's cached for at least 24 hours, but not necessarily on a specific schedule), but it also only factors in sites where you have more than 200 reputation.

Comment: I meant as far as how often it updates. The site is very clear that the network flair only applies to 200 and more. The reputation graph has no such disclaimer that I've seen.

Comment: The official explanation for how often the flair updates is that it updates no more than [once every 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65889/rep-value-on-the-new-flair-is-not-updated/65890#65890), and the window is, as far as I can tell, based on the last generation time for the image.