# How can I add other account graphics on my reputation chart?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why are not all my sites shown on the StackExchange reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101880/why-are-not-all-my-sites-shown-on-the-stackexchange-reputation-graph)

On StackExchange, clicking on my name on top of page and then clicking on Reputation (for me: https://stackexchange.com/users/167379/kokbira?tab=reputation), I can see reputation graph.

But it shows graph only for SuperUser account, not for my other accounts (StackOverflow etc.):

[image]

In all of them, I enter with Google login.

How can I add other account graphics on my reputation chart?

Comment: I think only accounts above a certain rep boundary (200?) are shown here.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I just saw a answer that saw the same... (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go , @amelvin answer). Please, answer my question (not on comments) and I'll assign the orrect answer to you :)

Answer (score 4):

Like the flair image, the Stack Exchange reputation chart only includes accounts with 200 rep or more.

Only your Stack Overflow account meets that criterion; other accounts will join it on the graph as soon as they pass the 200 rep point.